# Legality of publishing a website in directory?

Tags: links, legal, directory

I want to make a list of biggest websites that run on specific platform. I won't mention the platform here but let's say **xy** for example. So basically it will be a directory where each site will be described with couple of words and with a name and link.

Is there any risk that any company could sue me for this because I will reveal information about which platform they use? To recognize that they probably run on xy platform I will check if a specific URL exists in their domain. Platform xy has a specific URL key on all domains, that is how I know they run on this platform. This is actually public because everyone could do the same, but still, I am not sure about the legality of publishing their site on the list.

Answer (score 4):

I'd estimate that the risk is small.

- You are working with publicly available information (hitting a public URL on their server)
- If they don't want to be in your directory, they would probably contact you for removal before filing a law suit.
- Other sites are already out there that reveal what technologies are used.  For example http://builtwith.com/